# Gradle multi-project setup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I will have the following setup:

```
MyRootProj
    |
    ---- MyJavaProj1
    |
    ---- MyJavaProj2
    |
    ---- MyWebProj
```

I want to do the development on `Eclipse` and have installed `BuildShip` plugin.

From [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/creating-a-subproject-with-buildship-in-eclipse/15272) discussion it seems that its not possible to create a multi-project setup in `Eclipse` for `Gradle`.

I tried the following steps:

I created a directory `MyRootProj` and inside that ran:

```
gradle init
```

This created the default files.

Then I modified the build.xml of `MyRootProj` to:

```
plugins {
   id 'eclipse'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin : 'eclipse-wtp' 
    apply plugin : 'java'
}
```

Till this point everything is fine.

Now following the steps in above link, I create `MyJavaProj1` directory under `MyRootProj` and add a blank `build.gradle` inside it.

I then modify the `settings.gradle` file of `MyRootProj` to:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyRootProj'
include 'MyJavaProj1'
```

And then did a `gradle refresh` on the root project as recommended.

This creates the `MyJavaProj1` with all the files. However, this does not have a `Gradle` recommended package structure for java projects already.

When I right click on eclipse project explorer and do a `New -> Gradle Project`, the project which gets created comes with `src-main-java`, `src-main-test`, etc. structure out of the box.

Why does that not happen with the way I am creating `MyJavaProj1` above?

Long story short, I have created the root project. Now I want to create sub projects. However, I want to do it in Eclipse and I want the sub-projects to have autocreated `Gradle` recommended structure for Java Projects.